# How do I debug openstack-install command?

Tags: software-installation, openstack, log, openstack-autopilot

Is there a debug command or log that can be viewed to look into `sudo openstack-install` error

Answer (score 1):

I believe the logfile name is printed out on the last line of output when running the command.

```
~/.cloud-install/commands.log
```

Also [see these tips](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/Installer/debugging/single-install).